# Moving to 64-bit on OS X?

Tags: macos, 64-bit

What is the best practice for moving to 64-bit on OS X? Using the 10.6 SDK and 64-bit intel as my SDK and target.

I have int32 types to change

Does OS X have an 'int64' or would one use a 'long long'?

Where might I find a resource to available data types?

What other issues are there?

Answer (score 6):

Apple has exactly the documentation you want, called [64-bit transition guide](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/intro/intro.html). OS X uses LP64 model, so you should use

```
#ifdef __LP64__
```

etc. to conditionally compile things according to the bit width, especially if you want your code to be 32bit/64bit clean.
For Cocoa, see  [64 bit Transition Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). There, `NSInteger` has an appropriate bit width according to the mode, so you don't have to deal with the bit width yourself.

Comment: @yuji - we need the app to be 64-bit only.

Answer (score 1):

Both `long` and `long long` are 64-bit types when building 64-bit on OS X.  In addition, you can use the `int64_t` and `uint64_t` types defined in `<stdint.h>` if you need to specify that an integer is exactly 64 bits wide.

You generally don't need to change existing `int32` types in your program, unless they're being used to perform pointer arithmetic (or otherwise depend on them being the same size as a pointer).  32 bit arithmetic continues to work just fine in 64-bit programs.  If you *do* have variables that must be the same size as a pointer, use the `uintptr_t` type, which will work in both 32- and 64-bit builds.

The other situation where you might need to make changes is if a API expects to be passed (or returns) a `size_t` or `long` or `intptr_t`, and you've been using `int` all this time, instead of what the function in question actually specifies.  It will have worked on 32-bit builds, but may introduce errors when built for 64-bit.

**Yuji**'s suggestion of reading the 64-bit transition guides is excellent advice.

Comment: @stephen - We need the app to be 64-bit only.

Comment: @stephen - Can you explain a bit more? I want to be 64-bit only. I am using the 10.5 SDK and 64-bit intel as my target settings. I have int16, in32 and some longs.

Comment: @ML - have you tried just building your application for 64-bit without changing anything?  If your code doesn't do anything "clever" with pointers, it may work just fine as is.